# Dart: Future<void>.then(_) requires callback with parameter

Tags: flutter, dart

I feel like I'm probably way overthinking this... but I was working with the Flutter Camera module and wrote the following code:

```
controller = CameraController(camera, ResolutionPreset.medium, enableAudio: false);

controller.initialize().then((_) {});
```

However... This confused me, as `controller.initialize()` returns a Future, and the `.then()` requires a parameter of type `void`. I attempted writing the `.then` Future without a parameter, and I got a compilation error.

So my question is: why does the callback on completion of the `Future<void>` need to have a parameter at all, if the result is an empty type?

Thanks for any insight!

Comment: Dart 1 didn't have strong typing and had a much weaker notion of `void`.  Also see [The curious case of `void` in Dart](https://medium.com/flutter-community/the-curious-case-of-void-in-dart-f0535705e529) and [Future<void> vs Future<Null>, what’s the difference?](https://medium.com/dartlang/future-void-vs-future-null-whats-the-difference-84a42d616e7d).

Comment: @jamesdlin awsome. Thanks, I'll look at it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually that's because of the signature of the `then` method.

The `then` method signature looks like:

```
Future<R> then<R>(FutureOr<R> onValue(T value), {Function onError});
```

As you can see the `then` is expecting a callback function `onValue` as an argument.

The `onValue` callback indeed takes one argument and returns a `FutureOr` ( `FutureOr<R>` is actually a type union of R and Future, meaning the return value can either be of type R or Future).

The analysis server, analysing the code will actually expect the `onValue` callback to match the specified type regardless of it's argument type being a `void`.

Hope that helps!

Comment: That makes perfect sense. Thank you!